# mvc formatting text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, text, formatting

i have text like this

div bla-bla end div

i need to get only 'bla-bla' without div, because of i need to call substring in controller only to text bla-bla not to div tags. is it possible

p.s. how to input tags here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have jquery you can access inner html by calling ( for example ):

```
$("#idofthediv").html()
```

to set the conntent of the div:

```
$("#idofthediv").html('some html')
```

Answer (score 0):

document.findElementById(..).innerText;

Comment: no, i need call substring before view be show , formatted text stored in database

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using a Regular Expression.

There is a sample of what you want to do at [Regular Expression Examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).  It's the first sample in the section titled "Grabbing HTML Tags" near the top of the page.